# Retrieve profile picture of each user parse iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In my iOS app. there is twitter like feed. and each feed has username, profile picture and the tweets he has added.

and im able to retrieve username to each feed but cannot retrieve the profile image. here is my code

```
let spread:PFObject = self.LiveFeedData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    var user = spread.objectForKey("spreader") as! PFUser

        user.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (obj: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if obj != nil {
                var fetchedUser = obj as! PFUser
                var username = fetchedUser["username"] as! String

                cell.username.text = user.username // This Works FINE

            }
        }

        if let userImageFile = user["photo"] as? PFFile{
        userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                if imageData != nil{
                cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                }else{
                    println("No Data")
                }

            }else{
                println(error)
            }
        }

        }
```

[image: This iS Tweet Feed]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're inside the if let statement at all?

Comment: @thefredelement just checked it. No. i think problem is from that statement :(

Comment: Are you the user that's trying to access the user photo?

Comment: @thefredelement i have updated the question with parse screenshots. no any user can see the app. every users will see the each feed uploaded persons Username and his Photo

Comment: I can not see the ACL column which is most important here, parse user ACL is usually defaulted to that user only meaning only the current user can access their own instance of the User class.

Comment: @thefredelement Updated with ACL column. but im retriving username without problem. having problem with Image file only

Comment: I don't see a photo column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86790/discussion-between-axonlivelabs-and-thefredelement).

Comment: if (error != nil) while fetching the PFFile content should be if(error == nil)

Answer (score 3):

As discussed, using a PFImageView may help streamline the code that you need to move into your fetch closure.

```
    user.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (obj: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if obj != nil {
            var fetchedUser = obj as! PFUser
            var username = fetchedUser["username"] as! String

            cell.username.text = username

            cell.profileImage.file = fetchedUser["photo"] as! PFFile
            cell.profileImage.fetchInBackground()

        }
    }
```