# How to load attributes of different Parse Objects Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In my Parse Data Browser, I have two classes: "Books" and "User." In my "Books" class, I have a pointer named "pointUser" that points to the "User" class. I can load the username from the "Books" class, but i can't load the user profile picture from the "User" class. I would show a screen shot, but I don't have enough points to do so. But this is my code so far, and it doesn't work...

```
    if let userBooks = PFObject(className: "Books").objectForKey("pointUser") as? PFUser {
            userBooks.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (obj: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if obj != nil {
                    var fetchedUser = obj as! PFUser
                    if let userProfilePicture = fetchedUser["userProfilePicture"] as? PFFile {
                        userProfilePicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                            (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                            cell?.RPUserProPic.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                        }
                    } else {
                        cell?.RPUserProPic.image = UIImage(named: "Gender Neutral User-32")
                    }

                } else {
                    print("could not retrieve user class")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: why you are not using a PFImageView from ParseUI ?

Comment: I am using PFImageview

Comment: then you should do `cell?.RPUserProPic.file = userProfilePicture 
                                cell?.RPUserProPic. loadInBackground ()` if `cell?.RPUserProPic ` is a PFImageView

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work. I think the problem is trying to set a column of class as an object (User). Also, my problem is exactly like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963918/retrieve-profile-picture-of-each-user-parse-ios-swift

Comment: the problem of the question you mentioned is he is checking if error != nil and he should check if error == nil. I am using PFImageView and it works well. i am also using a user as a column of other class and it works

Comment: I know how to load files, I've done it multiple times. If I use as! PFUser, then will I be able to access all attributes within Parse's User class?

Comment: yep, in your case if book has one user

Comment: OMG I'm an idiot. So maybe I should be using relations: Books is like a newsfeed where each user posts book recommendations!